# best encryption method

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

What is the most standard encryption technique used  in sql server for asp.net c# enterprise level application? . i am talking with respect to standards like md5 or sh1 etc, hashing

Comment: Hashing and encryption are not the same thing at all. Please describe what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This question is confusing... where does SQL Server use encryption at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is called hashing, not encryption.

I think you can use some form of SHA-2, possibly after concatenating with a 'salt' string. Most common platforms provide built-in functions for such hashing algorithms. Details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

Answer (score 1):

- Enterprise applications don't store passwords. They use NTLM/Kerberos integrated security and rely on impersonation and [constrained delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739587%28WS.10%29.aspx) to secure access end-to-end.
- Hashing and/or encryption as a means to protect against accidental media loss is much better served with [Transparent Data Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx), which encrypts an entire database transparently.
- Password hashing against a compromised host disclosure of passwords which opens the potential of password reuse on unrelated sites can use built-in hashing functions like [`HashBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx). As long as the hash is properly used (correctly salted). But with a compromised host the battle is already lost.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally found Md5 (with salt) to be quite common.

**However**

I've seen time and time again, where the login page(s) are done via standard http! 
This is a bigger concern then someone hacking into web-server/ SQL box and getting hold of the passwords.

Read about the [Cookiemonster Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookiemonster_attack) for more information regarding ['Man in the Middle'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle) type security issues.